# How should I retrieve the access to my Cloud DNS domain configuration settings when I've deleted the project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a public domain for my personal use that was once managed by Route53, but have later on moved to GCP's Cloud DNS.

But with my terrible misunderstanding, I have deleted entire project that used to contain the Cloud DNS access.

Is there any way to retrieve this access, or is there any adequate contact point that I can resort to with such problem?

Answer (score 0):

I understand you had a public domain configuration settings in Cloud DNS in your project and you have accidentally deleted the project. If you have not deleted the configuration settings in Cloud DNS before deleting your project then I would like to share with you the [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#restoring_a_project) on Creating and Managing Projects section ‘Restoring a project’ :

Project owners can restore a deleted project within the 30-day recovery period that starts when the project is shut down. Restoring a project returns it to the state it was in before it was shut down.

Just to mention here that Cloud Storage resources are deleted before the 30-day period ends, and may not be fully recoverable.